# Retrieving and displaying value from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase and displaying it on recyclerview. I encountered an error (Error below) while trying to run the app. I wonder if it's the loop causing the error or because I am getting the wrong value. Can anybody help me with this? I'm trying to get the notification messages ("test", "test2") stored in my firebase. Will show the image of the database below.

**Error**

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type

**Database**[image]

**NotificationFragment.java**

```
   private void prepareNotification1() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String userID = user.getUid();
        mRef.child("customers").child(userID).child("Notification").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    System.out.println(postSnapshot.getValue());
//                    System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getKey());
//                    Log.d("value", dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    Notification menu = postSnapshot.getValue(Notification.class);
                    notificationList.add(menu);
                }
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

**Notification.java**

```
public class Notification {
    private String notification;




    public Notification(){
    }

    public Notification(String notification){
        this.notification = notification;
    }

    public String getNotification() {
        return notification;
    }

    public void setNotification(String notification) {
        this.notification = notification;
    }
}
```

I can post my adapter codes if needed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to directly convert a `String` into a `Notification`. 
Firebase will return a String that you can use to create your Notification.

You can try the following code to create the Notifications from the data from Firebase.

```
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Notification menu = new Notification(postSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
    notificationList.add(menu);
}
```

Comment: I get an underlined error when I try to use that code                   >Notification
(java.lang.String)
in Notification cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Try with `postSnapshot.getValue(String.class)`

Comment: Glad it worked. Can you set it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
mRef.child("customers").child(userID).child("Notification").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Notification menu = postSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                notificationList.add(menu);
            }
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```